# Execute custom routine for GL_LINEAR interpolation

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a texture with each pixel consisting of two floats: `glTexImage2D(target, 0, GL_RG32F, width, height, 0, GL_RG, GL_FLOAT, data)`.

These two color channels are combined into one in a fragment shader via `length(texture2D(texture, texcoord).rg)`.

With `GL_LINEAR` interpolation, each of two channels is interpolated separately.

I want to apply linear interpolation after the texture was processed (that is after `length(texture2D(texture, texcoord).rg)`).

Is there a way to interpolate `length(texture2D(texture, texcoord).rg)`, rather than each of two channels?
Is there a way to supply our own routine for `GL_LINEAR`?

I'd imagine it goes something line this:

1. Produce processed texture via `length(texture2D(texture, texcoord).rg)` using `GL_NEAREST` interpolation.
2. Apply `GL_LINEAR` interpolation onto resulted texture.
3. Proceed with the rest of the fragment shader.

Comment: How often does the texture change? In case it is static, I would store the length in a texture as you described. If it changes very frequently, doing the interpolation manually in the shader (lookup closest texels yourself) could also be an option.

Comment: Texture changes very often. Current workaround is to manually (outside of shader program) process buffer on each change and use texture with each pixel consisting of 1 float. I will look into interpolation in the shader, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately texturing units aren't programmable at this time. I've always wandered why they don't take the unification of GPU components one step further and instead of having separate texturing units integrate relevant unique functionality into the unified cores (like srgb->linear rgb conversion) and pack more of them in a chip.